# Guardar XML modificado desde codigo con python

Tags: python, xml

Tengo un xml donde modifiqué los datos de una etiqueta en específico.
Ahora sólo quiero guardar el xml de modo que éste quede modificado.
Apenas conozco de python, así que cualquier consejo, bienvenido.
Este fué el code que utilicé para modificar la etiqueta:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('archivo.XML')
etiqueta_raiz = doc.getroot()
for etiqueta_secundaria in etiqueta_raiz:
    for item in etiqueta_secundaria:
        monto = float(etiqueta_secundaria[6].text) / 100000
    monto = str(monto)
    etiqueta_secundaria[6].text = monto
    print etiqueta_secundaria[6].text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer eso una es usando los metodos de acceso a archivos por ejemplo.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Open a file
fo = open("test.xml", "wb")
print "<newtag value='x'> </tag>"

# Close opend file
fo.close()
```

Otra usando alguna libreria que te permita disponer de una interfaz para leer y escribir archivos xml, por ejemplo `ElementTree`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

et = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('text')

# Agregar nueva etiqueta <a x='1' y='abc'>body</a>
new_tag = xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement(et.getroot(), 'a')
new_tag.text = 'body'
new_tag.attrib['x'] = '1' 
new_tag.attrib['y'] = 'abc'

#  Guardar en el archivo final
et.write('file_new.xml')
```

Comment: Funcionó con import xml.etree.ElementTree, gracias!